# Installing Mongo and chown /data/db yields "illegal user name" error

Tags: mongodb, sudo, chown

I'm installing MongoDB for a Node / Express tutorial and upon creation of the /data/db folder and the following command:

`sudo chown 'id -u' /data/db`

I received the following error:

```
chown: id -u: illegal user name
```

Answer (score 21):

You can look for the current username and then try setting the permissions.

```
$ whoami
username
$ sudo chown username /data/db
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

The reason this failed is because your syntax was wrong and you misinterpreted the quoting from the source where you found it. You need to use a quote like this to **execute** the `id` command:

```
chown `id -u` /data/db
```

See the difference?

Also you seem to have arrived here at a misconception of how to install mongodb, and possibly have gone for a build from a tarball. The `/data/db` path is **not** required, it's just the default location.

But you generally can get a package install for your system:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

These will typically lay out an installation with a directory structure appropriate to your system conventions, and create a `mongodb` user under which the `mongod` process runs, with all appropriate permissions. They typically have a config file that you can set options in as well. The process is also typically set-up as a "service", so you don't need to manually invoke it each time you want to use.

You can specify the [--dbpath](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption--dbpath) option on startup or within a [config file](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#dbpath) section, which of course is loaded by the [--config](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption--config) option.

At any rate you *should* generally run `mongod` processes as their own user (not root) using the options and permissions on data and logging directories set for that user.

Comment: i did use backticks but i still get that same error. i believe my shell fish was causing the issue. i temporarily switch to bash to runt he command and it was fine